# perl search digits in my string

Tags: string, perl, search

I have problem with search digits in my string.
I have two files.

stver.php

```
define('upd_ver', 256);
```

tr_ver.php

```
define('code_ver', 110);
```

The problem is: how to find digits (256 and 110) make increment and save files.
Exmpl, string define('upd_ver', 256); after saving becomes define('upd_ver', 257);

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$sv="stver.php";
$tv="tr_ver.php";
open (SVIN, $sv) || die "Can't open $sv";
while (<SVIN>)
{ chomp; print;}
print "\n";
close (SVIN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
s/(define\(.*?,\s*)(\d+)/"$1" . ($2 + 1)/eg;
```

The `/e` flag causes the replacement-string to be evaluated, and its *result* substituted in, rather than the replacement-string itself being simply plopped in as a literal string.