# replacing older digits by newone after increment

Tags: perl, file, increment

Q: How to add this info $sv? Replace older by new one.

$ less stver.php

```
define('update_ver', 328);
```

$ less rec.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$sv="stver.php";
open (NUMECHO, "$sv") || die "Can't open $sv";
while (<NUMECHO>=~m/(\d+)/g)    #digits output
{
 chomp;
 #print "$1\n";
 $b=$1;
 $a=$b;
 ++$a;
}
close (NUMECHO);
print "Old value = $b\n";
print "New value = $a\n";
```

When i run script

```
$ ./rec.pl
Old value = 328
New value = 329
```

All I need is to replace 328 by 329 into stver.php

Comment: If I understand you correctly, after you run `rec.pl` you want `stver.php` to read `define('update_ver', 329);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl search digits in my string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415946/perl-search-digits-in-my-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works as you excpect, adding 1 to stver.php's number each time you execute it:

**rec.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$sv="stver.php";
open (NUMECHO, "<$sv") or die("Unable to open $sv");
open (TMP, "> $sv.tmp") or die("Unable to open $sv.tmp");
while(<NUMECHO>) {
    if(/(\d+)/) {
        m/(\d+)/g;
        $b = $1;
        $a = "$b" + "1";
        s/$b/$a/;
    }
    print TMP $_;
}
close(NUMECHO);
close(TMP);
rename "$sv.tmp", $sv;
print "Old value = $b\n";
print "New value = $a\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i.bak -pe's/define\('\''update_ver'\'', \K(\d+)(?=\);)/$1+1/e' stver.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/define('update_ver', 328);/define('update_ver', 329);/" stver.php
```

You'll be left with stver.php containing the information that you want and a backup called stver.php.bak containing the original information.

Comment: No, $a and $b should be replaced automatically. as auto-incriment function do. Code from rec.pl is just the part of another script